# Алгоритм работы промокода в корзине товаров

Tags: php, jquery

Всем привет. Есть ситуация такая, нужно реализовать скидочные промокды для корзины товаров. Как я вижу это сделать:

Промокод храниться в БД, пользователь переходит в корзину и если знает промокод вбивает его. Когда введут 12 символов (кол-во символов промокода 12), будет отправляться ajax запрос, на поиск этого промокода и его скидки. Если нашел то общую сумму уменьшаем на процентную ставку. Но есть вопрос, как отработать запрос один раз и больше не отсылать, потому что если он успешен, он может удалить и опять вбить промокод и промокод опять сработает, нужно что бы он отрабатывал один раз. Создать переменную на стороне php которая будет присваиваться допустим 1 когда промокод успешно активирован, и потом проверять, если 1 то запрос не отсылаем, но тогда получается некрасивый синтаксический костыль. Какое решение вы бы сделали,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно производить расчет стоимости товара для бэкенда только после отправки формы (не менять никакие данные по ajax запросу).

На клиенте можно проверять промокод на валидность при каждом изменении. Если размер промокода меньше 12, то показывать полную сумму, а если 12 - то проверять и обновлять сумму (но только на клиенте).

Comment: ну получается если он обновит страницу то промокод исчезнет? а хочется что бы он его вбил, активировал и все